# Does Symantec Endpoint Use Windows Server User Licenses?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, anti-virus, symantec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

I'm evaluating how many user licenses I need for Windows Server 2008.  There will only be two users who need physical / remote desktop to the server itself, but I plan to install Symantec Endpoint on this server.  Will I need more licenses for Windows based on how many machines are using Endpoint?

Comment: I don't think the two are related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user that accesses a server requires a CAL.  There are multiple ways to aquire CALS.  You can learn about CALS here: [Client Access Licenses](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/client-access-license.aspx)

Comment: This answers my question the best, I think.  If I understand corerctly, the user needs a CAL even if they're connecting to a non-Windows service?

Comment: correct any connection to a windows server requires a cal.  That being said it's extemely likely that you already have one (as long as you bought user cals) for the rest of your environment.

Answer (score 1):

No, Symantec Endpoint and Windows CALs are completely separate. You need a Symantec license for every machine you will install on, not for each user.